# Text in HTML going off page

Tags: html

I have a webpage that has it's text-centered but some of the text at the top goes off the page on smaller devices and mobile devices. The page leaves a space at the bottom but cuts of the top part. I have tried adding breaks to the top but that still does not help. Any solutions on how to get it to not cut off and let it start from the top of the page would be useful. Below is the entire code for the page. If the part that is causing it could be located that would be helpful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 10;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="hero-text">

    <h1 style="font-size:50px">Page Title</h1>
    <h3>Subtitle</h3>
    <h4>pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</h4>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at. Interdum varius sit amet mattis. Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac. Est velit egestas dui id ornare. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at. Interdum varius sit amet mattis. Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac. Est velit egestas dui id ornare. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis.
    </p>

    <p>Copyright &copy; 2016-<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> Example. All Rights Reserved.<p>

    <p style="font-size:10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras.</p>

  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set `width:100%;` to `.hero-text`  class, since it is a absolute element.

Answer (score 0):

Set a max height of 100vh to your hero text, this will move the scrolling from the page to the text box.

Comment: This works, but the text is not centered on the page.

Comment: That's true, as the other commenter mention, using flexbox is an other great option. But another more backwards compatible/old school way of doing it is with the table styles. A great example is here.
https://www.vanseodesign.com/blog/demo/vertical-centering/table-cell.php

Answer (score 0):

The text is going off the page because of `position: absolute`. You generally want to avoid absolute positioning unless you have to use it.

You can achieve the centering by giving the text container a width of 50% and setting the horizontal margins to auto. It also looks like you want to vertically center it, which you can do with Flexbox. I set the body height to 2000px to show the vertical centering in action.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 2000px;
}

.hero-text {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* vertical centering */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-text">

  <h1 style="font-size:50px">Page Title</h1>
  <h3>Subtitle</h3>
  <h4>pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</h4>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at. Interdum varius sit amet mattis.
    Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac. Est velit egestas dui id ornare. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at. Interdum varius sit amet mattis.
    Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac. Est velit egestas dui id ornare. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis.
  </p>

  <p>Copyright &copy; 2016-
    <script>
      document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
    </script> Example. All Rights Reserved.
    <p>

      <p style="font-size:10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 10;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
}

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .hero-text {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="hero-text">

    <h1 style="font-size:50px">Page Title</h1>
    <h3>Subtitle</h3>
    <h4>pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</h4>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at. Interdum varius sit amet mattis. Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac. Est velit egestas dui id ornare. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at. Interdum varius sit amet mattis. Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac. Est velit egestas dui id ornare. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis.
    </p>

    <p>Copyright &copy; 2016-<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> Example. All Rights Reserved.<p>

    <p style="font-size:10px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras.</p>

  </div>



</body>
</html>
```